# Communicate notification data from messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler to webpage

Tags: firebase, service, firebase-cloud-messaging, worker

I am trying to communicate data received by the service worker back to webpage.

On the webpage 'navigator.serviceWorker.controller' is null. The sevice worker has self.client as empty.

Any samples or directions will help

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is get a list of window clients which will return a list of the tabs for your origin and then post a message to each window client. (This code would be in the `setBackgroundMessageHandler()` ):

```
const promiseChain = clients.matchAll({
    type: 'window',
    includeUncontrolled: true
  })
  .then((windowClients) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
      const windowClient = windowClients[i];
      windowClient.postMessage(data);
    }
  })
  .then(() => {
    return registration.showNotification('my notification title');
  });
  return promiseChain;
```

Then to receive the message in the page, add a listener like so:

```
 navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    console.log('Received a message from service worker: ', event.data);
  });
```